# Intel link option: Qipo (interprocedural optimization)

Tags: visual-studio, optimization, linker, intel, icc

When creating an Intel C++ project in Visual Studio, the default setting for link optimization is "Interprocedural Optimization=Yes", and at the same time the C++ setting for this feature is "No".

Is there any benefit in using link IPO without specifying the C++ IPO?

My link time is preposterous only because of this link option.

Comment: link-time optimization lets your compiler optimize across/between `.cpp` files, inlining small functions even if they're not in `.h` files.  It can make your final executable a *lot* faster, if you have a lot of small accessor functions but keep them out of headers so less code has to be recompiled when changing the internals of one class.  Slow link times are worth it if you want a fast executable.  You might leave the option off during normal development, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes, are you saying there's no connection between link-time and compile-time IPO?

Comment: I don't know how ICC works, I usually use gcc and clang.  It's possible that C++ IPO means only within each file, while link-time enables writing the necessary info to object files allow link-time optimization between procedures in different files.  Any normal level of optimization will already allow normal inlining within the same file of one procedure into another, though.  But anyway, if it actually takes a long time to link, it's probably doing something useful.

Comment: @PeterCordes, please concatenate your comments into one answer and I will accept it.